# Criar Extensão para Chrome com script PHP

Tags: php, html, google-chrome-extensão

Eai pessoal fiz uma extensão para o chrome só com um html básico e funcionou super de boa.

O problema está quando mudei o arquivo principal de .html para  .php para poder colocar a minha logica que preciso do php. Alguém saberia me dizer como fazer para rodar o script php? pensei em talvez ler ele pelo javascript, mas não sei se isso funciona.

Comment: Para o PHP ser executado ele precisará ser processado por um servidor que possui o interpretador devidamente instalado e configurado. Como extensão do navegador você não conseguirá utilizar, apenas JavaScript. Dependendo do que precisa fazer, talvez será necessário a extensão enviar os dados via HTTP para um servidor seu rodando o PHP e respondendo com os dados desejados.

Comment: aah muito obrigada, não tinha me ligado nisso hahaha que não tinha como interpretar. Eu andei dando uma olhada que da para fazer com python e converter para javascript tu acha uma boa ?

Comment: Tem como implementar, no html da extensão, faz um iframe pro seu site com a página em php, ou faz um Ajax no HTML pra uma página sua em PHP que passa as informações que você precisa mostrar pro usuário, existem n soluções pra isso :)

Comment: aqui que ta isso seria para o meu tcc que estou desenvolvendo ai ideia da extensão é ler um google docs com api e interpretar esse texto com a api do google de pln.

Comment: Gdocs Tem suporte pra JS: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/js vê se isso pode te ajudar!